# Replacing whole div in Internet Explorer

Tags: css

I have got `<div id="head">` where I placed my logo made in CSS. The only problem is that it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. So I'd like to ask if there is any way to replace whole div with another div if it's opened in Internet Explorer. I want to open `<div id="headIE">` with image of that logo in Internet Explorer instead of using CSS which doesnt work in it.

Thank you.

Example, this will be opened in Google chrome

```
<div id="head"><h1>Logo</h1></div>
```

but if it's going to be opened in Internet Explorer then it's not going to open `<div id="head"><h1>Logo</h1></div>` but it will open this.

```
<div id="headIE"><h1>Logo</h1></div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Provide some code and explain further please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) like so:

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <div id="headIE"><h1>Logo</h1></div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
  <div id="head"><h1>Logo</h1></div>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

but it would be better if you try to write CSS that works in all Browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Changing HTML element ID's in this way is quite a hacky approach to cross browser compatibility. You should try instead to write CSS that works across the different browsers you wish to support. If you have an example of the header image issue you have, a CSS fix would be much cleaner.

Comment: Well it's huge `font-shadow` which would take forever to create for Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional comments for IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
Special IE logo
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
Normal logo
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to find a solution that works for IE and other browsers, what about adding an image tag for your logo instead of css + text-indent replacement?  But, if you really want to you can target IE via jQuery and change the ID.  ex:

```
if($.browser.msie) {
  $('#head').attr('id','headIE');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code:

```
<div id="head">
    <!--[if IE]>
        <img src="hateIE.png" align="middle">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE]><!-->
        <h1>Mira's</h1><br>
        <h2>Koding place</h2>
    <!--<![endif]-->
</div>
```